Accessibility for customized file input
I have this kind of customized file input:


#file-uploader {
  display: none
  }
<input type="file" id="file-uploader" multiple accept=".stl"/>
<label for="file-uploader" role="button" aria-labelledby="drop-file-instructions" tabIndex=0>
  Add files
</label>



I simplified this a lot for the sake of readability, but the problem remains: In this accessibility tree, the label is well detected as a button and focusable but the only way to trigger the file selector is by clicking on the button.
Does anyone have a solution to trigger this by keyboard ?
edit: this is a from a react project, so any react solution is fine with me too

If you're using react, please post react code and add the tag?

this is basically more of a html design problem than a react one because it does not include any react mechanism, and as you can see I do have the same problem in vanilla. Having a pure html solution would also help more people than a specific react question

Add a keypress listener to the label, which then fires .click on the input. ✅

It should be noted that as soon as you add role="button" to a <label> element, it completely loses its semantics as a label. So you may as well just use <button>.

You need to hide the file input visually – applying display:none or visibility:hidden removes an element from the accessibility tree and prevents it from being focused via keyboard/tab navigation.
A common technique is to shrink the element to 1px and apply some clipping
.visually-hidden {
  clip-path: inset(50%);
  height: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 1px;
}

See also "The a11y project: Hide content".


.label-file:focus-within{
  outline: 1px solid red
}

.visually-hidden {
  clip-path: inset(50%);
  height: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 1px;
}
<label class="label-file">
  Add files
    <input type="file" id="file-uploader" class="visually-hidden" multiple accept=".stl"/>
</label>



The example above wraps the <input> in the label.
This way we don't need a for or an ARIA label attribute as the label itself contains a descriptive text. Besides, we don't need to add a manual tab-index. So we can simply focus the input via keyboard.
For a focus style you could use :focus-within pseudo selector or :has()
